# How can I set the 'text' value of a TextView to be based off an EditText value or variable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-edittext

I'm currently trying to make a DnD character sheet app using Android Studio for my University Final Year Project, and I'm having some issues with creating my layout. I am currently tinkering with having a TextView present it's text field as a specfic value i.e in this case I wish to have it copy the value of the EditText component so that later I can try and have a TextView present the modifier based on the overall stat value (i.e if the EditText has the value 14 then the TextView will show +2).

The issue I am having is that I don't know how to assign the text value of my TextView to be equal to what I wish it to be. I have tried in the java file to set a String to be equal to the component, but all I am getting back is an integer value and not the String.

Any advice or input would be helpful as I am very new to using Android Studio and app development.

**Main Activity Java File**

```
package com.finalproject.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.finalproject.app.databinding.ActivityDiceRollerBinding;
import com.finalproject.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;

    String test = String.valueOf(R.id.editTextCharacterName);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTest) ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());
        allocateActivityTitle("Character Sheet");



    }

    public void onClick(View v){

    }
}
```

**Main Activity xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.08"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CharName_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Character Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCharacterName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextCharacterName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextCharacterName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCharacterName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="John"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.03"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.003" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="198dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text in an EditText we use getText so the code should be like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCharacterName);
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

and here you can use the text in the editText

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your answer to my question. I have tested your solution using a button onclick event to see if it would take the string value and it worked like a charm; I assume the getText() works for TextViews also?

Comment: yes @CS_Noob_360. It works fro text view also. You could try to check that yourself :/